# SQL updating column with a difference value of current and previous row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that that contains cumulative rain fall data. I want to calculate the rain fall for each record and update the table with that value.

The table looks like this:

| ID | date | WsRaincount | Rain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-01 13:01 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 2023-07-01 13:05 | 10.2 |  |
| 3 | 2023-07-01 13:10 | 10.3 |  |

The result should be :

| ID | date | WsRaincount | Rain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-01 13:01 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-07-01 13:05 | 10.2 | .2 |
| 3 | 2023-07-01 13:10 | 10.3 | .1 |

I can calculate the the difference using the `LAG()` function:

```sql
SELECT  
    ([wsraincount]) - (LAG([wsraincount]) OVER (ORDER BY [id])) AS RainDiff
```

My problem is how do I now take the `RainDiff` value and place it in the proper rain column?

Comment: Why would you want to store it, it would change every time someone changed or deleted a row? Just calculate it when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an updatable derived table or CTE (and update it directly, no need to rejoin).

```sql
UPDATE WithDiff
SET Rain = RainDiff
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      wsraincount - LAG(wsraincount) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RainDiff
    FROM yourTable t
) WithDiff;
```